# Conditional probability density function of two variables

Tags: probability-theory

Assume I am given a continuous function $f(x_1,\cdots x_n)$ over some $n$-dimensional region $R$.

I want to show that this function is a jointly continuous probability density function.

May I show this in **a general case** by proving that 
$\int\cdots\int f(x_1,\cdots x_n)dA = 1$ over the region $R$? Is this condition necessary and sufficient?

Comment: You also want $f$ to be non-negative. If that's the case, then $f$ is the density of some random variable with values in $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Right, $f$ must be non-negative. So? May I show this function is jointly continuous probability density function by integrating?  Is this condition necessary and sufficient?

Comment: Could you provide any reference, book for example, where I could find similar statement or definition?

Comment: Yes, in that case $P_f(A)=\int_A f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ for $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defines a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks!!! But how can I accept the answer, can't see any button.